# C# replace by regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have below C# code to remove stop words from a string:

```
public static string RemoveStopWords(string Parameter)
{
      Parameter = Regex.Replace(Parameter, @"(?<=(\A|\s|\.|,|!|\?))($|_|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|A|about|after|all|also|an|and|another|any|are|as|at|B|be|because|been|before|being|between|both|but|by|C|came|can|come|could|D|did|do|does|E|each|else|F|for|from|G|get|got|H|had|has|have|he|her|here|him|himself|his|how|I|if|in|into|is|it|its|J|just|K|L|like|M|make|many|me|might|more|most|much|must|my|N|never|no|not|now|O|of|on|only|or|other|our|out|over|P|Q|R|re|S|said|same|see|should|since|so|some|still|such|T|take|than|that|the|their|them|then|there|these|they|this|those|through|to|too|U|under|up|use|V|very|W|want|was|way|we|well|were|what|when|where|which|while|who|will|with|would|X|Y|you|your|Z)(?=(\s|\z|,|!|\?))([^.])", " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
      return Parameter.Trim();
}
```

But when I run it, it works when the stop word in not at end of the string, for example:

`about this book` output is `book`

`manager only` output is `manager only`

`only manager` output is `manager`

Can anyone please guide?

Comment: `([^.])` i think that part at the end might be your problem. what happens with the input `"manager only "`? (notice the space at the end)

Comment: When we have space at the end e.g. "manager only " it's replaced to "manager "

Comment: The character class at the end `[^.]` expects at a single character to be present. But you use a positive lookahead to assert what is directly to the right is either `!` `?` `,` a whitespace char or end of string. So this part `([^.])` can also only contain what is asserted before it, you could omit the lookahead and just match it instead. You can also shorten the pattern a bit by making use of character classes instead of using the `|` to sum up all the alternatives for the single characters.

Comment: Thank you so much, so what I understand from your comment is that you are suggesting to remove this part from the regular expression `([^.])` right? Can you please also elaborate on the shortening of  the pattern?

Comment: For example `(?<=(?:\A|[\s.,!?]))(?:$|[A-Z0-9_]|about|after|all|also|and?|another|any|are|a[ts]|be|because|been|before|being|between|both|but|by|came|can|come|could|did|do|does|each|else|for|from|get|got|ha[ds]|have|her?|here|him|himself|his|how|i[nf]|into|i[st]|its|just|like|make|many|me|might|more|most|much|must|my|never|not?|now|o[fnr]|only|other|our|out|over|re|said|same|see|should|since|so|some|still|such|take|tha[tn]|the[nm]?|their|there|these|they|this|those|through|too?|under|up|use|very|want|wa[ys]|we|well|were|what|when|where|which|while|who|will|with|would|your?)(?=(?:\s|\z|[,!?]))`

Comment: Thank you so much @the-fourth-bird, its working perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capture group at the end of the pattern `([^.])` requires a single char other than a dot. The looakhead preceding that `(?=(\s|\z|,|!|\?))` limits that match to only one of the listed alternatives (it can not match a dot already as it is excluded by the lookahead).

If you want to keep that, you could omit that lookahead, and just match what you would allow to match like `([\s,!?]|\z)` but it would still require at least 1 of the listed alternatives.

What you could so is only use the positive lookahead, and update it to `(?=[\s,!?]|\z)`

```
(?<=\A|[\s.,!?])(?:$|[A-Z0-9_]|about|after|all|also|and?|another|any|are|a[ts]|be|because|been|before|being|between|both|but|by|came|can|come|could|did|do|does|each|else|for|from|get|got|ha[ds]|have|her?|here|him|himself|his|how|i[nf]|into|i[st]|its|just|like|make|many|me|might|more|most|much|must|my|never|not?|now|o[fnr]|only|other|our|out|over|re|said|same|see|should|since|so|some|still|such|take|tha[tn]|the[nm]?|their|there|these|they|this|those|through|too?|under|up|use|very|want|wa[ys]|we|well|were|what|when|where|which|while|who|will|with|would|your?)(?=[\s,!?]|\z)
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cA%7c%5b%5cs.%2c!%3f%5d%29%28%3f%3a%24%7c%5bA-Z0-9_%5d%7cabout%7cafter%7call%7calso%7cand%3f%7canother%7cany%7care%7ca%5bts%5d%7cbe%7cbecause%7cbeen%7cbefore%7cbeing%7cbetween%7cboth%7cbut%7cby%7ccame%7ccan%7ccome%7ccould%7cdid%7cdo%7cdoes%7ceach%7celse%7cfor%7cfrom%7cget%7cgot%7cha%5bds%5d%7chave%7cher%3f%7chere%7chim%7chimself%7chis%7chow%7ci%5bnf%5d%7cinto%7ci%5bst%5d%7cits%7cjust%7clike%7cmake%7cmany%7cme%7cmight%7cmore%7cmost%7cmuch%7cmust%7cmy%7cnever%7cnot%3f%7cnow%7co%5bfnr%5d%7conly%7cother%7cour%7cout%7cover%7cre%7csaid%7csame%7csee%7cshould%7csince%7cso%7csome%7cstill%7csuch%7ctake%7ctha%5btn%5d%7cthe%5bnm%5d%3f%7ctheir%7cthere%7cthese%7cthey%7cthis%7cthose%7cthrough%7ctoo%3f%7cunder%7cup%7cuse%7cvery%7cwant%7cwa%5bys%5d%7cwe%7cwell%7cwere%7cwhat%7cwhen%7cwhere%7cwhich%7cwhile%7cwho%7cwill%7cwith%7cwould%7cyour%3f%29%28%3f%3d%5b%5cs%2c!%3f%5d%7c%5cz%29&i=about+this+book%0d%0amanager+only%0d%0aonly+manager%0d%0athis&o=m)

A few notes about the pattern

- To shorten the alternation, you can for example a character class `a[ts]` to either match `at` or `as` or make a character optional `and?` to match either `an` or `and`
- Inside the lookarounds, you don't have to add another grouping mechanism, so you can use `(?=[\s,!?]|\z)` instead of `(?=(?:[\s,!?]|\z))`
- If you don't need the values of the capture groups `()` you can make them non capturing `(?:)`
- The numbers `1|2|3` and the characters `A|B|C` can be shortened to `[A-Z0-9]` and also matching the underscore, you might even shorten it to `\w`